# Ansible dynamic inventory python interpreter issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to run a playbook from virtualenv and I am using ansible-dynamic inventory script. 
Problem is: The inventory script is using default system interpreter not the one I have passed using "ansible_python_interpreter" variable.

The playbook works fine if activate virtualenv and run from the command line. Also, the inventory script works fine when I run using `/opt/myproj/.ve/bin/python3.6 inv.py`. 
But the playbook is invoked remotely by a different python script, not from the command line.

```py
/opt/myproj/.ve/bin/ansible-playbook playbooks/rotate_passwords.yml -i inv.py -e ansible_python_interpreter=/opt/myproj/.ve/bin/python3.6 -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.7.10
  config file = /opt/myproj/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/opt/myproj/library']
  ansible python module location = /opt/myproj/.ve/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /opt/myproj/.ve/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
Using /opt/myproj/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
/opt/myproj/inv.py did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/opt/myproj/inv.py did not meet yaml requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/opt/myproj/inv.py did not meet auto requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /opt/myproj/inv.py with script plugin: Inventory script (/opt/myproj/inv.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/myproj/inv.py", line 11, in <module>     import pymysql.cursors ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

I expect the inv.py should get invoked with given ansible_python_interpreter where I have installed all pip modules.

Comment: @path ansible_python_interpreter = The target host python path. This is useful for systems with more than one Python or not located at /usr/bin/python such as *BSD, or where /usr/bin/python is not a 2.X series Python. We do not use the /usr/bin/env mechanism as that requires the remote user’s path to be set right and also assumes the python executable is named python, where the executable might be named something like python2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible inventory scripts don't receive any special Python substitution behavior like modules do. Since they can be written in any language, the only requirement is that the execute bit is set and a valid shebang is in place. So it's going to literally run whatever the shebang says.

A couple of options:

- Make the shebang on the inventory script `#!/usr/bin/env python` - that should inherit the venv Python from the controller.
- Rewrite the inventory script as an [inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#inventory-plugins). It's more complex, but a lot more flexible, and runs inside the controller, so sidesteps any Python configuration issues once your controller is working properly.

Comment: Thank you! inventory plugin is working like a charm. FYI.. shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`  is not working, it's still using the default python.